# How can I pass named arguments to phantomjs file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

We can pass unnamed arguments to phantomjs and write the following code to console log all arguments.

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

if (args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
} else {
  args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
  });
}
```

So if we run phantomjs file using `phantomjs index.js 1 2 3`, the console will log: `1 2 3`.

My question is how can I pass named arguments to phantomjs file so that I can start my script like:

```
>phantomjs index.js --username=user1 --password=pwd
```

Comment: You have to parse the arguments yourself. PhantomJS wouldn't do that for you, but CasperJS would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read named arguments this way (this is very quick & dirty):

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

args.forEach(function(arg, i) {

    var argValue = arg.split('=');

    if(argValue.length == 2) {
        var arg = argValue[0].replace('--', ''),
            value = argValue[1];

        console.log(arg + ": " + value);
    } else {
        //Handles unnamed args
        console.log(arg);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
% phantomjs args.js --foo=bar                                  
args.js
foo: bar
```